# Does anybody know of a XSL-FO Rendering WebService?

Tags: web-services, xsl-fo

I am looking for a XSL-FO Rendering webservice. FOP does not fit our needs, and commercial server versions currently are too expensive.

So I was wondering, are there webservices available that render your FO document for a cost/page or something?

Comment: Do you mean: a web presence to which you submit docs and get back results, or a code base that implements XSL-FO that you can deploy as a service?

Comment: I was referring to the first option. The cost for our own deployment would be to high, since we would use it not very often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [**Apache FOP**](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) and stand up your own service, for free.

There is even an [example servlet available in the FOP distro and instructions for **How to use Apache FOP in a Servlet**](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/0.95/servlets.html#example-servlets).

Comment: Hi, As outlined in my question, FOP doesn't fit our needs. It doesn't implement some part of XSL-FO, which we can't work around, and won't be implemented by the FOP team.

Comment: Do you have any budget, or are you looking for a free solutions? Ibex http://www.xmlpdf.com/ is a great product with a pricing model that is  per-developer, so could be an affordable solution.

Comment: Also, what is it that FOP doesn't handle that you require?

Comment: The missing feature was auto-sized table support. I remember having evaluated ibex solution, but it lacked even more things than FOP. (It surely is a nice product, but for our specific needs it's not usefull)

Comment: I finally decided to go with Amazon EC2 and FOP. It only is powered on when I need it, thus saves a lot of money! Powered by a ruby queue server.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to visit http://www.renderx.com/ and find out XEP product. 
The XEP Engine is written in Java and runs on most Unixes, Microsoft Windows, Linux, Mac OS X and other systems where Java Virtual Machine 1.1.8 or newer is available.
And also XEP Engine is available in two license models, XEP Desktop and XEP Server.
I think it would be useful.

Comment: Yes, I know RenderX. In fact, it's the best renderer I know. But I need it to be a low-cost renderservice. The cost of a serverlicense is too high. Therefore, I would want a paid webservice, that I can submit the XSL-FO to. RenderX powered service would be totally cool. (Maybe I should start a service myself... :) )

Comment: Looks like renderX added cloud formatter which is a remote rendering service. I am not sure on the pricing but it seems like the answer OP was looking for